# Converting the following C++ code into Object C or C Class

Tags: ios

I could rename the C++ codes into .mm file and change all .m files in project to .mm But there's a confusing error in one of the .m file after changed to .mm

```
         CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = inPropertyValue;
```

It said Cannot initialize a variable type `CFDictionaryRef (aka 'const_CFDictionary*) with an value of type 'const void*'

I don't know such error after renaming everything to .mm

Anyway, I have the original .CPP file
MeterTable.h

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <math.h>


 class MeterTable
 {
public:

MeterTable(float inMinDecibels = -80., size_t inTableSize = 400, float inRoot = 2.0);   
~MeterTable();

float ValueAt(float inDecibels)
{
    if (inDecibels < mMinDecibels) return  0.;
    if (inDecibels >= 0.) return 1.;
    int index = (int)(inDecibels * mScaleFactor);
    return mTable[index];
}
 private:
float   mMinDecibels;
float   mDecibelResolution;
float   mScaleFactor;
float   *mTable;
  };
```

MeterTable.CPP
      #include "MeterTable.h"

```
 inline double DbToAmp(double inDb)
 {
  return pow(10., 0.05 * inDb);
 }

 MeterTable::MeterTable(float inMinDecibels, size_t inTableSize, float inRoot)
: mMinDecibels(inMinDecibels),
mDecibelResolution(mMinDecibels / (inTableSize - 1)), 
mScaleFactor(1. / mDecibelResolution)
 {
if (inMinDecibels >= 0.)
{
    printf("MeterTable inMinDecibels must be negative");
    return;
}

mTable = (float*)malloc(inTableSize*sizeof(float));

double minAmp = DbToAmp(inMinDecibels);
double ampRange = 1. - minAmp;
double invAmpRange = 1. / ampRange;

double rroot = 1. / inRoot;
for (size_t i = 0; i < inTableSize; ++i) {
    double decibels = i * mDecibelResolution;
    double amp = DbToAmp(decibels);
    double adjAmp = (amp - minAmp) * invAmpRange;
    mTable[i] = pow(adjAmp, rroot);
}
```

}

```
   MeterTable::~MeterTable()
{
free(mTable);
}
```

any ideas to rewrite the C++ file to real Object C Class? It's pretty short.

Comment: Do you mean Objective-C?

Comment: there is neither Object C nor C classes.

Answer (score 0):

I've had very hard-to-track down issues like this when I have mixed C++ and Objective-C code.  If you are setting the document to be Objective C++ from the properties in XCode, make sure you do the same for the Objective-C file which is calling out to the C++ code, and is #including the needed C++ header file.

I have had this before, and it gets the strangest error messages.  If this is not the case, sorry for clouding the answers here.  Sometimes it gets more difficult to track down when there are multiple header files including the C++ class reference.  It would not hurt to set all the files (if it is not a large project) to be "Objective C++".